# Closing PowerQuery error message with PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powerquery

Sorry for the vague title, I'm really struggling in figuring out what's the correct approach here.

I'm running `Excel VBA` automation through Windows 10 `Task scheduler` + `VBScript`. Several workbooks are opened in sequence + VBA script is run, workbook + Excel application are closed and then proceeded to another (depending on day, there can be 5+ workbooks that are cycled through).

Most of them include `PowerQuery` connection that is refreshed with VBA, but it sometimes produces a weird error message that I don't know how to avoid. I can't properly re-produce the issue since it doesn't always occur.

**Although the query runs fine, it will hang after completion and require manual    interference for the script to continue, ruining the point of automation**. The screen below is shown, expecting user to click `Close` button. Details information is extensive, but not too informative, other than:

```
Error Message:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

Once I manually click `Close` VBScript continues to run and I won't have any additional problems. Before that there is also `Unexpected Error` running in Task Manager. If I end specifically this (sub?)task from Task manager, `Unexpected Error` popup also disappears and VBScript continues to run. If I end the primary `Excel` task, my VBScript will crash and won't continue.

I have pondered if I can run a parallel task - perhaps in `PowerShell` to check if a subtask `Unexpected Error` is running. And if so, kill it. Unfortunately `Get-Process` only lists the primary `Excel` process and does not list `Unexpected Error` window. Is there some way I could programmatically check if the `Unexpected Error` window is open and if so, close it?

I do understand it's not a remedy to the original problem, but hoping it to be an immediate  fix regardless.

[image]

Comment: Check object to make sure they are not null before you use the objects.  Is error random or does it always occur with same data?

Comment: I don't know if it'll help in your situation, but note the the Excel COM Automation server has an `.Interactive` property that defaults to `$true`; setting it to `$false` is designed to suppress interactive prompts.

Comment: @jdweng could you please clarify how to check if object is/is not null in PowerQuery? What is an object in PQ? As of specific query that produces the error - a bit difficult to know for sure, but it's usually more or less the same query. But it does feel like it's almost always a query where web API (REST) is connected to. And again - I run the same queries once every day. The error is not present every day, but 1-2 times per week.

Comment: For testing in PS, I usually just add the variable on a line by itself to see the value or use $myVariable | Format-List

Comment: @jdweng, I'm late to this answer, but needed to test some more. It is random - HOWEVER, this randomness always seems to happen with running VBA in Excel files that have data queries to external REST API-s.

Comment: You are probably accessing a webpage that has Java Scripts running and you must wait for the java to complete before accessing the data.  As I said in my first response you have to check to make sure the object is not null.  See following for solutions : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/web/web-troubleshoot#handling-dynamic-web-pages